# Plot an interval graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

This is my DataFrame:

[image]

How would I go about plotting this data in equal time intervals. Like say time 0-20 shows a bar that represents the number of experiments that took time 0-20 and another bar that shows the number of experiments that took say 21-40 soo on and soo forth

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby base range then use `seaborn` or `plt.bar` for plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate random number for dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=39.9, size=(100,))})

# Set range for group
rng = np.arange(0, 41.0, 20.0)

grp = df.groupby(pd.cut(df["Time"], rng)).size()

# Plotting
sns.barplot(x = grp.index, y = grp.values)
plt.show()

# Or if you want only matplotlib
#pandas below 0.17.0
# grp.plot('bar')

#pandas 0.17.0 and above
grp.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Output `seabron`:

[image]

Output `matplotlib`:

[image]